# Rolling Average in SQL without using BETWEEN

Tags: sql, date, select, group-by, window-functions

Let's say I have a table `signups` in the format:

```
| date       | sign_ups |
|------------|----------|
| 2018-01-01 | 34       |
| 2018-01-02 | 23       |
| 2018-01-03 | 2        |
| ...        | ...      |
```

I now want to write a query to compute the preceding 7 day average of signups, i.e. for a given day, the average of its signups and the values of sign ups for the previous six days. This [blog post](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/rolling-average) offers this solution:

```
select
  date,
  avg(sign_ups) 
    over (order by date asc
          rows between 6 preceding and current row) as avg,
from signups
```

I don't like using SQL's `BETWEEN`, so I wrote this solution instead:

```
SELECT 
  a.date, 
  AVG(b.sign_ups)
FROM 
  signups a 
JOIN 
  signups b ON a.date <= b.date + interval '7 days'
GROUP BY 
  a.date
```

Just wanted confirm the two are equivalent, and if there are more concise/more efficient solutions to this problem.

Comment: You don't like `between`???? You are not supposed to pick friends from language syntax. It works. It gets the job done efficiently. What else do you want?

Comment: Why don't you simply run both and compare the results? It's easy to spot that the 2nd returns something totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries are not equivalent :

1) As answered by @GordonLinoff, the first query returns just as many records as there are in the table, while the second aggregates by date. For the results to be the same, there should be just one row for each date

2) This :

```
rows between 6 preceding and current row
```

Is not equivalent to :

```
a.date <= b.date + interval '7 days'
```

First of all, as commented by Dnoeth, the second form it will average the current date and the last 7 days, which represents **8 days total**.

Also, the second form will take in account records within the last N days, and also every records **after the current date**.

You would need to change that clause to add an upper bound to the date range, like :

```
a.date <= b.date + interval '6 days' AND a.date >= b.date
```

Which basically emulates `BETWEEN`... and can also be spelled :

```
b.date BETEWEEN a.date - interval '6 days' AND a.date
```

Comment: And even after the rewrite it still averages 8 days instead of 7 :-)

Comment: @dnoeth : ah yes you are right, I did not pay attention to this... I updated my answer :

Answer (score 3):

First, assuming you really mean:

```
on b.date <= a.date and
   b.date > interval '7 days'
```

Then they are only equivalent if you have exactly one row on each date.

Your version is quite different -- you are taking values *after* the date in the `join` but before the date in the windows function.  You have 8 values in one case and some unknown number in the other.  But I get the gist of the question.

The window function version is much, much, much, much preferred over the self join.  From a performance and understandability perspective, this is simply better.  And, as your code amply demonstrates, the windows version makes it easier to express your actual intention.